# Binding `helm-toggle-visible-mark-forward` to a key in `helm-map`

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, emacs-helm

## Setup

I have these key bindings of Helm commands:

```lisp
  (define-key helm-map (kbd "C-a")       #'helm-select-action)
  (define-key helm-map (kbd "C-n")       #'helm-next-page)
  (define-key helm-map (kbd "C-p")       #'helm-previous-page)
  (define-key helm-map (kbd "TAB")       #'helm-next-line)
  (define-key helm-map (kbd "<backtab>") #'helm-previous-line)
  (define-key helm-map (kbd "C-TAB")     #'helm-toggle-visible-mark-forward)
```

## Problem

All of these work except for the last line, `helm-toggle-visible-mark-forward`.  When I hit C-TAB in the Helm completion window, I get the error message, `<C-tab> is undefined`.

## What I've Tried

Using `\t`

```lisp
(define-key helm-map (kbd "C-\t")     #'helm-toggle-visible-mark-forward)
```

-- same result, `<C-tab> is undefined`

Using `<C-tab>`

```lisp
(define-key helm-map (kbd "<C-tab>")     #'helm-toggle-visible-mark-forward)
```

-- `wrong type argument, commandp`

Removing `#`

```lisp
(define-key helm-map (kbd "C-TAB")     'helm-toggle-visible-mark-forward)
```

-- same result, `<C-tab> is undefined`

Using `M-TAB`

```lisp
(define-key helm-map (kbd "M-TAB")     #'helm-toggle-visible-mark-forward)
```

-- `wrong type argument, commandp`

Using a lambda

```lisp
(define-key helm-map (kbd "M-TAB")     (lambda () (interactive) (helm-toggle-visible-mark-forward)))
```

-- `symbol's function definition is void: helm-toggle-visible-mark-forward`

## Question

Is it possible to rebind `helm-toggle-visible-mark-forward`?  If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't use tag `elisp` for questions about using Elisp. It's for questions about the nature of the language, compared to other languages, in particular other Lisp dialects. Thx.

Comment: Edited - you originally wrote "remapping", but this isn't about that. Command "remapping" is about remapping the keys bound to one command to a different command. See [Remapping Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Remapping-Commands.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`helm-toggle-visible-mark-forward` and `helm-toggle-visible-mark-backward` [were added](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/commit/35e2faae1c748dbfe7dc611d2f32f0d04c8f1d01) in v3.6.1.  The [latest release](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/releases) (as of 2020-04-25) is v3.6.0. Hence, you would need to install from source if you want to use these functions.  Otherwise, they will be **undefined**.

As a workaround, you can add them directly to your configs before your key bindings like so:

```lisp
  ;; Adding these functions here until they become available in the main source in version 3.6.1
  (defun helm-toggle-visible-mark-forward ()
    (interactive)
    (helm-toggle-visible-mark 1))

  (defun helm-toggle-visible-mark-backward ()
    (interactive)
    (helm-toggle-visible-mark -1))

  (define-key helm-map (kbd "<C-tab>")     #'helm-toggle-visible-mark-forward)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```lisp
(define-key helm-map (kbd "<C-tab>")     #'helm-toggle-visible-mark-forward)
```

Pass the form that Emacs help returns for a key sequence you press to `kbd`. `C-h k` followed by `Control` with `Tab` tells you:

> **`<C-tab>`** runs the command ...

See the Elisp manual, node [Function Keys](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Keys.html), which says this:

> `backspace`, **`tab`**, `newline`, `return`, `delete`
>
> These keys correspond to common ASCII control characters that have
>        special keys on most keyboards.
>
> In ASCII, `C-i` and `<TAB>` are the same character.  If the terminal
>        can distinguish between them, Emacs conveys the distinction to Lisp
>        programs by representing the former as the integer 9, and the
>        **latter as the symbol `tab`**.
>
> Most of the time, it’s not useful to distinguish the two.  So
>        normally `local-function-key-map` (*note Translation Keymaps::) is
>        set up to map **`tab`** into 9.  Thus, a key binding for character code
>        9 (the character `C-i`) also applies to `tab`.  Likewise for the
>        other symbols in this group.  The function `read-char` likewise
>        converts these events into characters.

---

But you say that you already tried

```lisp
(define-key helm-map (kbd "<C-tab>")     #'helm-toggle-visible-mark-forward)
```

and Emacs told you this -- and it told you the same thing when you tried to bind it to `M-TAB` (which is the same thing as `C-M-i`):

```
 -- wrong type argument, commandp
```

That means that `helm-toggle-visible-mark-forward` isn't defined as a command. Did you load the file that defines that function?  And does that function's definition have an `interactive` spec (so it is in fact a **command**)?

And this attempt also suggests that you have not loaded the file that defines the function:

```lisp
(define-key helm-map (kbd "M-TAB")     (lambda () (interactive) (helm-toggle-visible-mark-forward)))

  -- symbol's function definition is void: helm-toggle-visible-mark-forward
```

(Another possibility is that you loaded a file that has a command with almost the same name, and you misspelled the command name.)

Comment: Thank you.  You were right - they are not defined.  They are set to be added in the upcoming version of Helm, 3.6.1.  I have clarified this in my answer and posted what I'm using as a work-around. Thanks again.